# Is it possible to play encrypted videos using exo player?

Tags: android, encryption, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to play encrypted videos using Exo player. Initially, I tried like uploading the encrypted file to the server and storing them in the server with encryption key when I want to play the video through my application I will be downloading the file into my local storage and decrypting and then playing. All this process is working fine with no issue but it is taking much time to play a single video which is very annoying, So I came to know that Exo player somehow supports playing the encrypting video with online streaming. I got some resources[https://github.com/rohanisuhadi/DemoStreamingEncryptionExoplayer/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/suhadi/demostreamingencryptionexoplayer]. By using these resources I tried to play the encrypted video which is not playing the problem is I can able to get the stream but the stream is not getting played by Exo player due to that I am finally ending with the following exception. Please kindly help me with.

```
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:924)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:846)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Given that you are decrypting client-side anyway, have you tried just slotting a `CryptoInputStream` between your network stream and the player...?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark yes exactly